# Handle EDIT ACTION in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am trying to edit a post in my react-redux project where i do it like this

My post.js

```
 <div className="Heading_with_icon_story">
              <span className="post_heading">{item.storyTitle}</span>
              <p className="both_icons">
                <img src={edit} alt="miss-mistake" className="edit-icon" onClick={()=>this.editStory(item)} />
                <img
                  src={trash}
                  alt="miss-mistake"
                  className="edit-icon"
                  onClick={() => this.deleteStory(item._id,item.userID)}
                />
              </p>
            </div>
```

then hereby action gets called
action.js

```
export const editStoryAction = (itemId) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/edit-story", {
      method: "POST",
      body: itemId,
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        dispatch({ type: EDIT_STORY, payload: response.data });
        Router.push("/edit-story");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Eror in adding");
        dispatch({ type: EDIT_STORY_FAIL, payload: err });
      });
  };
};
```

then comes reducer into play 
reducer.js

```
  const getEditStoryReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case EDIT_STORY:
        return action.payload
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };

  export default getEditStoryReducer;
```

and then finally comes edit page where i am facing the issue

```
class editStory extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      storyTitle: "",
      storyDescription: "",
    };
  }




  render() {

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Header />
        <main className="share_content">
          <p className="Share_heading">What's your story ?</p>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.props.storyDetails.storyTitle}
            placeholder="what is your story called ?"
            className="share_input_title"
            onChange={(e)=>this.setState({storyTitle:e.target.value})}
          />
          <textarea
            type="text"
            value={this.props.storyDetails.storyDescription}
            placeholder="your experience and what did you learn from it.."
            className="share_input_description"
            onChange={(e)=>this.setState({storyDescription:e.target.value})}
          />

          <button className="Share_button" onClick={()=>this.handleSubmit()}>Post !</button>
        </main>
      </React.Fragment>
    );

  }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log(state)
  return {storyDetails:state.getEditStoryReducer};
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { verifyToken,editStoryAction })(editStory);
```

so i get my input boxes filled with the data correctly but i am unable to change it , via onChange method, means i am nbale to write it ...is it so cause upon onChange my component get re-rendered and then again picks up data from state which is given by reducer
IF yes then how can i tackle this ?

Note - I am not using redux form here.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you're setting the value of your `input` components to the values you get from the redux store. But when changing your `input` values you also need to update the values in redux store. These sort of components are called controlled components but normally we use component state to control them and not redux state. Read more about them here: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

To resolve this bug you just need to use `defaultValue` prop instead of `value` prop for values coming from redux and use `value` prop for your component state like this:

```js
<input
    type="text"
    defaultValue={this.props.storyDetails.storyTitle}
    value={this.state.storyTitle}
    placeholder="what is your story called ?"
    className="share_input_title"
    onChange={(e)=>this.setState({storyTitle:e.target.value})}
/>
```